# How can I call a master.php file from inside a folder without losing all the paths?

Tags: php

I am making a website with just PHP. In order to make the header and footer easy to update, I made a `master.php` file with contents like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../images/a-master-favicon.ico" alt="a-master-favicon" >
    
    <title>Testing site</title>

    <link href="assets/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/head_footer.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    
    <?php $signed_request = $_POST['signed_request']; ?>
    <?php if(empty($signed_request)): ?>
        <?php include('header.php'); ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div id="eatSpace" style="margin-bottom: -175px;"></div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    
    <?php include($content); ?>
    
    <?php if(empty($signed_request)): ?>
        <?php include('footer.php'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
        

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

First off the `$signed_request` part is so I can show certain content when it's loaded via Facebook, that's not the problem.

The problem is that my folder structure is as follows:

```
root
|
|--assets
|    |
|    |--css
|    |--js
|
|--faqs
|    |
|    |--faqs-content.php
|    |--index.php
|
|
|--footer.php
|--header.php
|--index-content.php
|--index.php
|--master.php
```

So, when I call say, `index.php`, it looks like such:

```
<?php
    
$content = 'index-content.php';
    include('master.php');
```

This in turn calls `master.php` and that loads the entire site.

However, if I try to do the same in another directory (i.e. `faqs/`) and call `index.php` there, then the code looks slightly different:

```
<?php
    
$content = 'faqs-content.php';
    include('../master.php');
```

This loads everything just fine except no css or js loads at all because well the path inside the master file is on a different directory. How can I overcome this?

This is the first time I'm doing anything like this so I'm not sure if what I did is even the best way to go about it.

Comment: You could use absolute paths in your links e.g. `<link href="/assets/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your site is simple, you could get away with a combination of relative and absolute links. Your resources would have to use an absolute link like `<link href="/assets/css/sticky-footer-navbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>` whereas PHP links can be relative like you described.

However, it doesn't scale well to more complex apps, and can quickly get difficult to manage. Modern PHP frameworks make use of [PHP autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

If you don't like re-inventing the wheel, learn a good framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) or [Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/). These take care of autoloading and much more.

Comment: I'll certainly look into Laravel and Yii, thank you!